# how to use colorNumeric within addCircles in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I have a leaflet map in which I have used addCircles, which are sized based on the population size of my data locations. I now want to color those circles based on the income of the population using colorNumeric. How do I use the population variable to determine my circle radii and simultaneously use the income variable to determine my color?

````
```{r}
library(leaflet)

leaflet()%>%
addTiles() %>%
addCircles(data = censusdata3, lng = ~Lon, lat = ~Lat, weight = 1, radius = ~households_estimate_total, popup = ~Geography, group = "Population", color) 
```
````

Data sample:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kw2daQk5ur-A3HbdJt7K7krFZ9Uh9Xg726sFRlQXIUM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Sorry about that. I added a link to my google sheet with my data. Hope that works!

Answer (score 4):

I basically just combined examples from two `leaflet` tutorial pages: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html and https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shapes.html

You can build a color palette with `colorNumeric` or one of the other palette functions in `leaflet`, and then color the circles the same way you would for a choropleth.

The csv file is just what's downloaded from your spreadsheet.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

censusdata3 <- read_csv("censusdata - ACS_16_5YR_S1901_with_ann.csv") %>%
    setNames(c("Geography", "Lon", "Lat", "total", "median_income", "median_income_moe", "mean_income", "mean_income_moe")) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(total:mean_income_moe), as.numeric)

color_pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "magma", domain = censusdata3$median_income, reverse = F)

leaflet()%>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircles(data = censusdata3, 
                         lng = ~Lon, lat = ~Lat, 
                         weight = 1, 
                         radius = ~total, 
                         popup = ~Geography,
                         color = ~color_pal(median_income)
                         )
```

Not to editorialize, but I'd also suggest scaling the radius by the square root of the population, not the population itself, because people perceive the difference in area of circles. The example for shapes includes a similar map where they use `radius = ~sqrt(Pop) * 30`.

Comment: upvote for the editorial about using `sqrt` :^)